# How to put a vbox in hbox?

Tags: xetex, boxes, plain-tex

I tried this but it does not work:

```
\vbox{
  \hbox{
    {top-left}
    {top-right}
  }
  \hbox{
    \vbox{
      {bottom-left-top}
      {bottom-left-down}
    }
    \vbox{
      {bottom-right-top}
      {bottom-right-down}
    }
  }
}
\bye
```

bottom-left-top and bottom-left-down are rendered next to each other, although they are in a vbox. And bottom-right goes beyond the right paper size.

Comment: You need `\hbox` around the items in the `\vbox` if you want to stack them. What's your precise aim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\vbox{
      {bottom-left-top}
      {bottom-left-down}
    }
```

is the same as

`\vbox{bottom-left-top bottom-left-down}`

and sets a paragraph of text, broken into lines `\hsize` wide.

I think you intended

```
\vbox{%
      \hbox{bottom-left-top}%
      \hbox{bottom-left-down}%
    }
```

to vertically stack two hboxes in a vbox.