# How to vertically align two vboxes in a hbox at the top?

Tags: xetex, vertical-alignment, plain-tex

I tried this:

```
\hbox{
  \vbox{
    \hbox{1}
    \hbox{2}
    \hbox{3}
    \vfill
  }
  \vbox{
    \hbox{A}
    \hbox{B}
    \hbox{C}
    \hbox{D}
    \hbox{E}
  }
}
\bye
```

But the first vbox does not grow vertically.

Comment: Again: what's your aim? This particular problem is solved with `\vtop` instead of `\vbox`, but…

Comment: Together with [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528430/82917) this is starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/82917).

Comment: @campa I try to create a delivery note with a business letter layout in order to attach PDF files to Jira incidents. Last time I used LaTeX was in 2001. And now I want to use plain TeX to have more control about the positioning of the elements on the paper. So I am a newbie asking newbie questions. But the answers help me very much! Thanks!

Comment: I recommend the book *A Beginner's Book of TeX* by Seroul and Levy, which (IMO) is particularly good for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `\vbox` has no notion about the size of the second one, so the `\vfill` just adds zero glue.

If you want alignment at the top, use `\vtop`.

```
\hbox{
  \vtop{
    \hbox{1}
    \hbox{2}
    \hbox{3}
  }
  \vtop{
    \hbox{A}
    \hbox{B}
    \hbox{C}
    \hbox{D}
    \hbox{E}
  }
}
\bye
```

[image]

But it's rather difficult to understand what you want to achieve.