# Trying to align boxes with variable sizes

Tags: alignment, plain-tex

I'm trying to align some boxes, but having difficulty understanding why what I have isn't working and what I can do to get the desired effect with box primitives.

I want

```
x  the quick brown fox
   jumps over the lazy dog
y  sphinx of
```

I have

```
\hsize=2in
\vbox{
  \parindent=0pt
  \hbox to \hsize{
    \hbox to 20pt{\vbox{%
\vbox{x}%
\vbox{\vfill}%
\vbox{}
    }}%
    \vbox{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  }
  \hbox{
    \hbox to 20pt{\vbox{%
      \vbox{y}
      \vbox{\vfill}
      \vbox{}
    }}
    \hbox{\vbox{
\vbox{sphinx of}
    }}
  }
}
\bye
```

I'm sure I've done something wrong here. I don't want to use halign or similar, because shouldn't this be theoretically possible without it? hbox per row, each row has two hboxes, a short hbox for the "x" or "y" and longer wrapping hbox for the rest of the line, containing a vbox as the text spills downward. Maybe I need to set the height of the right vbox to the left vbox, but I'm not sure if that's possible or how to do that. Advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe a duplicate of [How to vertically align two vboxes in a hbox at the top?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528448/316068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example at [How to vertically align two vboxes in a hbox at the top?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528448), you may be looking for something like this:

```
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=2in
\newdimen\z
\z=\the\hsize
\advance\z by -20pt

\hbox{
  \vtop{\hbox to 20pt{x\hfill}}
  \vtop{\hsize=\z the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
}
\hbox{
  \vtop{\hbox to 20pt{y\hfill}}
  \vtop{\hsize=\z sphinx of}
}

\bye
```

which produces output like what you wanted:

[image: result]

[Fixing the baseline etc is left as an exercise :-)]

---

As for why your attempt doesn't work, let's simplify it a bit:

- In `\vbox{\vfill}` the `\vfill` does nothing, so we can remove it: `\vbox{}`.
- Similarly, the outermost `\vbox` does nothing in this example, and `\vbox{\vbox{sphinx of}}` is equivalent to `\vbox{sphinx of}`.
- So your input is equivalent (produces identical output) to:

```
\hsize=2in

\parindent=0pt
\hbox to \hsize{
  \hbox to 20pt{\vbox{\vbox{x}\vbox{}\vbox{}}}%
  \vbox{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
}
\hbox{
  \hbox to 20pt{\vbox{\vbox{y}\vbox{}\vbox{}}}
  \hbox{\vbox{sphinx of}}
}

\bye
```

Here, every `\vbox` (including each "empty" `\vbox{}`) uses the global `\hsize` of `2in`, which explains most of what you see.